# How to create new column in a df based on multiple conditions? using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, imputets

Here I need to create new column based in other columns

sample Data:

```
colum1       column2

M           online

L           offline

C           online

L           online

H           online

M           online

L           offline

C           online

L           offline
```

Here I need to create new column

column1 = 'M' & colum2 = 'online' --> 3 days

Column1 = 'M' & colum2 = 'offline' --> 5days

Like this I need to create new column

tried below code but I missed logic

```
sales['Shipment Tat'] = np.where ((sales['Order Priority'] == 'M') & (sales['Sales Channel'] == 'Online') ,  'with in 9 days' )
```

expected output

```
column1    column2       column3

M           online     3 days

M           offline    5 days

L           offline    5 days

C           online     7 days

L           online     7 days

H           online     9 days

H           offline    11 days
```

Comment: Can you add expected output? Are data [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I suggest use `np.select` with all conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` method -

```
def myFunc(record):
    if record['column1'] == 'M':
       if record'column2'] == 'online':
          return '3days'
       elif record['column2'] == 'offline':
          return '5days'
    return 'with in 9 days'

df['new_col'] = df.apply(myFunc, axis=1)
```